# javascript function distance between two points

Tags: javascript, function

i have been learning javascript for a few days. and im having problems with the sintaxis and the semantics of my programs, i can make run this simple problem. i dont know whats wrong with it

```
//2. **Distance between two points**. Create a 
//function that calculate the distance between two points 
//(every point have two coordinates: x, y). _HINT: Your function 
//Should receive four parameters_.


    function Point(x,y,x1,y1){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;

    this.distanceTo = function (point)
    {
        var distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(this.x1-this.x,2))+(Math.pow(this.y1-this.y,2)))
        return distance;
    };
}

var newPoint = new Point (10,100);
var nextPoint = new Point (25,5);


console.log(newPoint.distanceTo(nextPoint));
```

Comment: you passed "point" as a parameter but you're not using it within the function....

Comment: According to your instructions, it looks like they just want you do create a single standalone function which takes 4 parameters and returns the result. Your `Point` object goes above and beyond that requirement, and only needs 2 parameters.

Comment: You also have 4 function parameters but are only passing two when you do the `var newPoint = new Point(10, 100);`  It seems that you would want to have a function called `distance`, as opposed to `Point`, pass the pairs of coordinates to it, and then do that calculation and return the `distance` value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try This instead:

```js
    function Point(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    

    this.distanceTo = function (point)
    {
        var distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(point.x-this.x,2))+(Math.pow(point.y-this.y,2)))
        return distance;
    };
}

var newPoint = new Point (10,100);
var nextPoint = new Point (20,25);

console.log(newPoint.distanceTo(nextPoint))
```

In your distanceTo function you needed to refer to point.x and point.y instead as those are the points of nextPoint.

Hope this Helped :3

Answer (score 1):

`Point` constructor should have just two arguments `x` and `y`. And `distanceTo` should use the `x` and `y` of `this` point ant the other point (the one passed as parametter).

```js
function Point(x, y){ // only x and y
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.distanceTo = function (point)
    {
        var dx = this.x - point.x;               // delta x
        var dy = this.y - point.y;               // delta y
        var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // distance
        return dist;
    };
}

var newPoint = new Point (10,100);
var nextPoint = new Point (25,5);


console.log(newPoint.distanceTo(nextPoint));
```

**Note:** Since all `Point` instances have the exact same `distanceTo` function, it is better to define it on the prototype instead of redefining it for each instance which will only increase creation time and waste a lot of ressources.

This is better:

```js
function Point(x, y){ // only x and y
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.distanceTo = function (point)
{
    var dx = this.x - point.x;               // delta x
    var dy = this.y - point.y;               // delta y
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // distance
    return dist;
};

var newPoint = new Point (10,100);
var nextPoint = new Point (25,5);


console.log(newPoint.distanceTo(nextPoint));
```

More about prototpes [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)!

Comment: thank you some much, but i dont quite understand how my 4 parameters are working in my whole function.

Comment: @GerardoLeon See the **note** I add. Your code is not wrong, functions in javascript don't throw an error if the parametters are less or more than what the function expect. Error happens when the function is using those parametters that were not provided. Excess in parametter will never throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the hint in the wrong place. It's the `distanceTo` function that should take four parameters. 
Given the hint, I wouldn't bother with the `Point` constructor (although I do like that thinking in general, it just doesn't seem to be what this question's looking for. Just go with `distanceTo(x,y,x1,y1)`, and I don't think you'll have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to do this based on your code but since your function is expecting 4 inputs I went with that one.

```
 function Point(x,y,x1,y1){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.distanceTo = function() {
            return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(this.x1-this.x,2))+(Math.pow(this.y1-this.y,2)))
        };
}

var points = new Point (10,100,25,5);
console.log(points.distanceTo()
```

);

You also don't need to set the variable and then return it, you can just return the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `function Point(x,y,x1,y1)` gets four parameters, but you're declaring it with only two of them. 
At the `distanceTo` function you should relate to `point` which's parameter of your invoked function.

It should go like this; `point.x` gives you 'X' value of passed object.

@Edit: My solution for this "problem" is;

```
var Point = function (x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.distanceTo = function (point) {
    let calculations = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(point.x-this.x,2))+(Math.pow(point.y-this.y,2)));

    return calculations;
  }
}

var firstPoint = new Point(0,0);
var secPoint = new Point(2,2);

console.log(firstPoint.distanceTo(secPoint));
```